# Preparations for python 3: issue warnings?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am the main guilty of a reasonably large Python package which is used internally in our organisation. I am in the process of preparing the package for Python3; for the code I have control over myself this is quite doable - but there are many scripts "out in the wild" which will break if/when the organisation default interpreter is yanked up to 3.x. The typical situation is as follows:

Some random script I do not have conrol over:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    #   By manipulating the environment I will ...
                         #   ... eventually switch this to pick up python3
import company.package   #   This is Python3 safe.

...
print "This - will fail hard"
```

What I would like to do (if possible) was to insert some global warning directives in the "company.package" code which I control - so that users can get a warning before the global interpreter is yanked up to Python3. Is this possible?

Comment: A warning about what? About the package being ported to Python 3? About Python3-incompatible syntax?

Comment: That the script has Python3 incompatible syntax, which will lead to hard failure in the future. For the example above: the print "..." statement.

Comment: To avoid breaking everyone's code at once, perhaps you could strive for supporting both 2.x as well as 3.x? Virtually every nontrivial module that at one point supported 2.x still supports it (or at least supported it for several releases after introducing 3.x support).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect when a script is run in Python 2.x and issue an update warning like this:

```
import warnings
import sys

if sys.version_info < (3,0):
    warnings.warn("company.package will be ported to Python 3 soon. Make sure that your script is Py3k-safe!")
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to ensure that a Python script will run smoothly in Python3, apart from human inspection based on static analysis (e.g. with [`2to3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) tool) and/or extensive unit testing.

EDIT: Porting to Python 3 is not only a matter of syntax, but involves module renaming (like `urllib`, which was split, or `cStringIO`) and conceptual changes (like the bytearray/string distinction). There is no `import` magic to check that.

Comment: OK - by only looking at the version a warning will be emitted irrespective of whether the script is Py3K safe or not?! But from your text I assume that there is no programmatic way to achieve what I want? I also looked at this https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-September/082443.html ctypes based trickery - but no cigar?

Comment: No way. The `-3` flag switched on with the trick in the linked email will only detect some Python3-incompatible statements. It won't ensure that your code will run in Py3k.  Just let other programmers know that the transition is taking place and let them do their work in ensuring that their code is Python3-compatible.